# Mock httpBackend protractor with ngMockE2E doesnt work

Tags: angularjs, protractor, ngmocke2e

Folloing the basic guidelines as described here `https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-mock-e2e`

But still the normal REST call is being called.

```
'use strict'

var HttpBackend = require('httpbackend');
var backend = null;
var Injector = require('./helpers/injector');
var ngMockE2E = require('ng-mock-e2e');
var $httpBackend = ngMockE2E.$httpBackend;

describe("Login", function () {

    var loginJsonStub,
        loginPage = require('./pageObjects/LoginPage.js');

    beforeEach(function () {

        browser.get('http://localhost:9001/#');

        var injector = new Injector();
        injector.get('loginJson').then(function (result) {
            loginJsonStub = result;
        })
    });

    beforeEach(function () {
        ngMockE2E.addMockModule();
        ngMockE2E.addAsDependencyForModule('myApp');
        ngMockE2E.embedScript('../../app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js');
    });

    afterEach(function () {
        ngMockE2E.clearMockModules();
    });

    describe("Routing", function () {

        it('should redirect to answerset page immediately if only 1 project', function () {

            $httpBackend.when('POST', '/authentication/login').respond({data: 123});

            element(by.id('userName')).sendKeys('xx\\svijver');
            element(by.id('passWord')).sendKeys('password');

            //browser.pause();

            loginPage.nextButton.click();

            browser.getLocationAbsUrl();
            expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('answersets/1');
            expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toBe('answersets/1');

            browser.pause();

        });
    });
});
```

This shouldn't be that hard, can someone point me out what I am overlooking?
Tried several other third party vendors for mocking httpBackend but cant get it  to work. Maybe the initial $http call in the actual app is overruling the mocked one?

**--EDIT--**

Adding the ngMockE2e dependency, according to the Angular doc, to my main app `angular.module('qApp', ['...', '...', '...', 'ngMockE2E']);` results in all kind of weird errors:

Error: Unexpected request: GET http://qubus7.test.kmsgroep.com/api/localizations/en2
        No more request expected
    at $httpBackend (angular-mocks.js:1263)

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
angular.js:78 Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'qubusApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

         http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/$injector/nomod?p0=qubusApp(anonymous function) @ angular.js:78(anonymous function) @ angular.js:1677ensure @ angular.js:1601module @ angular.js:1675(anonymous function) @ MainController.js:4
angular.js:78 Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'qbs.models' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/$injector/nomod?    p0=qbs.models(anonymous function) @ angular.js:78(anonymous function) @ angular.js:1677ensure @ angular.js:1601module @ angular.js:1675(anonymous function) @ loginModel.js:3

angular.js:78 Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'qbs.models' is not   available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

And while runnin Protractor it all of a sudden sees references to my UI elements anymore, which makes sense sinds the isnt loading anymore.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it seems as if you are using an old, standalone version of ng-mock-e2e. You should use the version in **angular-mocks** from angular: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E

When you have included angular-mocks in your project, you can add the following in your test files:

```
beforeEach(function () {
    // choose a unique name for your mock-module, like httpMocker
    browser.addMockModule('httpMocker', function () {
        angular.module('httpMocker', ['ngMockE2E'])
            .run(function ($httpBackend) {
                // define your routes
            });
        );
    });
});
```